# what do the slash mean in the regex expressions?

Tags: regex

What is the regexp "[a-z0-9]\+" suppose to mean? Or specifically what is the "\" suppose to mean here? Is it right the no string in the world that matches that regexp?

Comment: I'm confused as to why did you add the tag "regex-lookarounds"... Could you perhaps clarify?

Comment: deleted, add it by mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` in `[a-z0-9]\+` means the literal plus character. It's needed because without the slash, the `+` would be a [one-or-more quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Compare:

- `[a-z0-9]\+` matches a Latin lower-case letter or number followed by a plus, e.g. `y+`
- `[a-z0-9]+` matches one or more Latin lower-case letter or numbers, e.g. `xy4`

Answer (score 5):

it is hard to say. it depends on **which RE** (BRE? ERE? or PCRE) do you use.

if you use **BRE**, the `\` gives `+` special meaning.

if you use **ERE/PCRE**, `\` takes special meaning of `+` away.

an example would be clear (with grep, default using BRE):

```
kent$  echo "aaaaaa+"|grep -o 'a+'
a+

kent$  echo "aaaaaa+"|grep -o 'a\+'
aaaaaa

kent$  echo "aaaaaa+"|grep -oE 'a\+'
a+

kent$  echo "aaaaaa+"|grep -oE 'a+' 
aaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes the "+" a literal + symbol. This would be matched by any character matching the first range followed by a + sign, such as `c+` or `5+`.

Without the slash, the + would mean "one or more occurences", so strings like `abc`, `t63`.

Answer (score 0):

The slash ("\") here is used to escape the `+`. 
`+` has a special meaning in regex: it means repeat the precceding item one or more times.

- `[a-z0-9]\+` means: Match one alphanumeric character and a plus sign ("+")
- `[a-z0-9]+` means: Match one or more alphanumeric characters

You can find more info on regex Quantifiers **[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)**.
You might also want to take a look at this **[Regular Expression Basic Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

A backslash (`\`)escapes special characters to suppress their special meaning. So here the special meaning of `+` is removed. It is considered as just a symbol. The usual meaning of `+` is to repeat the preceding block 1 or more times.

So in this case `[a-z0-9]\+` means a single lower case letter or a decimal digit followed by a +. `a+`, `b+`, `0+`, `1+` etc. are all valid expressions of this regular expression.